# Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 14

Tags: android

I've seen many topics similar to these, but I still didn't succeed solving it.

My gradle is like this:

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mobi.mobilitapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled = true
```

I also tried modifying the AndroidManifest.xml as in other posts ppl say, but I still got other problems

Comment: This question lacks so much information. What kind of project are you working on? Where did you get the error? Show the error log and your code in which you got the error. Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Because Google decided to end support since [Icecream sandwich (api 14/15)](https://androidcommunity.com/google-play-services-ending-support-for-api-level-14-15-20181207/). So now its supposed to be minimum api 16. And targetsdkVersion has to be [minimum 28 now](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk).